# iBeacon scan response formatting

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, ads, ibeacon

I would like to configure my Bluetooth Low Energy peripheral devices as iBeacons and send additional data without connecting. Scan response is the correct way to do this, but including my custom scan response is causing the iOS iBeacon callback not to trigger within my iOS app

This post clearly outlines how to format the advertising packet:  http://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/f/538/p/293551/1023580.aspx#1023580

I know iBeacons made by Estimote do have scan responses, so it is possible, but I can't find any good documentation for iBeacons.

What are acceptable scan responses for iBeacons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was including the data type "manufacturer data" in the scan response. I had a different company code than the code given in Apples preamble for iBeacon advertising packets. Removing this data made iOS recognize my device as an iBeacon and receive the scan response packet

Comment: Sounds like you got this working. Would it be possible using this technique to use the scan request (not response) signal to turn on an indicator on the ble device (like an LED) so that it knows the advertisement was received.

Answer (score 1):

You can see an example of a scan request/response sequence here:

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/BLE_sniffer_guide

I doubt that making a custom scan response from your beacon is stopping detections.  I think it is more likely that when you added the scan response you somehow altered your advertisement so that iOS no longer sees it.

Even if you get this working, I don't believe there is any way to make iOS be able to see the data from a scan response that came from an iBeacon.  If you want this data for use by other platforms then this may be fine.